# ILMerge ignores bindingRedirect

Tags: .net, app-config, .net-assembly, ilmerge, assembly-binding-redirect

I have Project A, which references assembly B and assembly C. Assembly B references assembly C, too, but in another version than in Project A. Both assemblies (B and C) are referenced in Project A via NuGet (though both assemblies are under my own control, so I could change the way they are built if i have to)
I hope this picture can illustrate what i mean:
Assembly hierarchy :

[image]

Within Project A I have an app.config which has a bindingRedirect on assembly C to point all version from 0.0.0.0 to 1.1.0.0 to version 1.1.0.0:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="C" publicKeyToken="447cd79fe2efd739" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

All assemblies (B and C) are signed and do have a strong name. If I build the project, all is working fine as the bindingRedirect gets considered by Visual Studio and always points to version 1.1.0.0 of assembly C.
However if I try to ILMerge the output of Project A (what is an assembly, too) with assembly B (1.0) and assembly C (1.1) I get the following error:

```
There was an error merging the assemblies: 
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: C.
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethod(Method method)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   bei System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   bei System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   bei System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   bei ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   bei ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

If I update the project of assembly B to also point to version 1.1 of assembly C all is working fine, but that is not what I want to achieve.

So I thinkt the problem is, that ILMerge is not considering the app.config of Project A.
Any idea of how to solve this problem without always updating all projects in the hierarchy chain? Or any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So far, the only other solution I have found is don't touching the AssemblyVersion-Attribute of project C and instead use the AssemblyInformationalVersion-Attribute. This way I am able to deploy newer versions using NuGet without having to update all projects in the hierarchy-chain.

Answer (score 0):

[ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) supports this scenario, and will redirect any call to assembly C to the merged version.

It does so without looking at the binding redirect however, and assumes the version you asked to be merged (on command line) is the only one you want to use. Behavior isn't really defined if versions `1.0` and `1.1` differ in an incompatible way though (e.g. a type used in B has been removed from C `1.1`)